# Proving the existence of a complex one dimensional subspace of non invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ be an integer $\geq2$ and let $A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that A and B are invertible and the set $\{A,B\}$ is linearly independent. Prove that there exists a one-dimensional subspace $W$ of $span(\{A,B\})$ such that no element of $W$ is invertible.

Essentially, all I have to do is show that I can create a non invertible matrix from a linear combination from $A$ and $B$. This is because any multiple of a non invertible matrix will result in a non invertible matrix. Currently, what I'm trying to show is that there exists $k_1,k_2\in \mathbb{C}$ such that there exists $c_1,c_2,c_3\in \mathbb{C}$ not all $0$ such that $$c_1(k_1a_1+k_2b_1)+c_2(k_1a_2+k_2b_2)+c_3(k_1a_3+k_2b_3)=0$$ where $a_1,a_2,a_3$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3$ are the row vectors of $A$ and $B$ respectively. I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Are $a_1,a_2,a_3$ row vectors or column vectors?

Comment: @YadatiKiran They are row vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pick an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A^{-1}B$ and consider the linear span of $\lambda A-B$.

Comment: Yes, from my testing that appears to be correct. I'm just having trouble understanding why.

Comment: @RyanGreyling $\lambda A-B=A(\lambda I-A^{-1}B)$.